# Trouble accessing oracle database using R (odbc package)

Tags: r, oracle, odbc

A colleague at work is having trouble using the odbc package function. I am trying to find help.

He is using an oracle database using R instead of running our traditional SAS programs, but he has not been successful. We are trying to find out what is causing the error messages below. Can someone help?

```
Attempt 1:

#Get the Oracle JDBC driver
jdbcDriver =JDBC("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
classPath="C:/instantclient_19_10/ojdbc8.jar")

Create connection string to the Database we want
connect.string <-
glue("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//{host}:{port}/{sid}",
host = "stdbprd01.states.bls.gov",
port = 1521,
sid = "lausonep")
print(connect.string)
#Establish connection to your database
con <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver,
connect.string,
user = "username",
password = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"))

Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1], :
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Attempt 2:

library(odbc)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
driver="Oracle in OraClient12Home1",
database="lausprd",
uid="aakre_n",
pwd="!QAZ1qaz@WSX2wsx",
host="stdbprd01.states.bls.gov",
port=1521
)

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: IM006: [Oracle][ODBC][ORA]-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver’s SQLSetConnectAttr failed
```

Comment: Please, chech [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-EF07727C-50AB-4DCE-8EDC-57F0927FF61A): you need to specify service name, not a sid, after `/`

Comment: did the connection works in , for example, in `sqlplus` ? the error is quite clear, the listener does not know anything about that service name

Comment: It depends if oracle client is 32 bit/64 bit. For 32 bit client on 64bit windows you have to use R 32bit, see here if it can helps. https://guillaumepressiat.github.io/blog/2019/11/oraclyr

Comment: was there a solution to this?