# Migrating from JDBC to ODBC in R

Tags: r, odbc

My question is [nearly identical to this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/moving-from-rjdbc-to-odbc/22419/9), and is piggybacking off of my other question I have up [right now here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76415249/visually-explore-oracle-database-in-rstudio-but-jdbc-connection) but this one is specifically about:

**I think I should be able to connect to my database through ODBC instead of RJDBC (per another end user I've talked to) and I cant get it to work.**

Background info:
We have an off-site database that we currently connect to with code like this inside of R:

```
library(RJDBC)
classpath_name="A:/ojdbc8.jar"

# Create connection driver and open connection
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", classPath=classpath_name)  
jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=website.com)(PORT=2879))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=pdblhs)))", "username", "password")  

rv_protocol_staff<-  dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, 
                                "select * From schema.rv_protocol_staff order by protocol_id, created_date")
```

RJDBC doesnt seem to work with the Rstudio connections pane so I'd like to try ODBC instead.

Talking to a colleague at a different institution that connects to the same database, I believe ODBC works.

Problem is, he sets it up using "ODBC Data Sources" in the windows search bar, and has set up a "wallet" and stuff, things I cant do at my institution because I dont have admin rights on my computer and its a nightmare to get it.

That said, googling around and I have found a ton of different suggestions for how you can connect without setting up a DNS, and I have tried all those different strings and none seem to work:

```
vdw = DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                     Driver= "Oracle in OraClient12Home1", 
                     DBQ = "website.com:2879/pdblhs",
                     Schema = "my_schema",
                     UID="myUsername",
                     PWD="MyPassword")
```

returns this error:
[image]

```
Conex     <- odbcDriverConnect("DRIVER=Oracle in OraClient12Home1;UID=myUsername;PWD=myPassword;DBQ=//website.com:2879/pdblhs;",
                               believeNRows = FALSE)
```

returns this error:

"TNS:Connect timeout occurred"

odbclistdrivers() returns this:

[image]

Lastly, I dont know if it helps, but I connect to it successfully in "Oracle Explorer" in VS Code with this string, am I missing something about translating this string to R?

[image]

Comment: I can't test Oracle connections, but the `odbc` method of `dbConnect` allows a `.connection_string="..."` argument. You might be able to take the connection string and use it directly? Try `dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string="{ADDRESS=...}")`. (I don't normally use this mechanism so I'm not familiar with all of the nuances, but try various perturbations, such as with/without the outer surrounding `{`/`}` braces, etc.)

Comment: @r2evans thank you.  I did one permutation of that once, with this:
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),Driver= "Oracle in OraClient12Home1", .connection_string="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=website.com)(PORT=2879))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=pdblhs)))")  it returned an error of: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified " .   I also tried it with " .connection_string="(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)" instead of "description=(address ">   Either way same error.  Also not sure where I'd put username/password

Comment: I think the parens and such are wrong. Adding to my previous comment, look at https://www.dofactory.com/connection-strings#oracle for some similar connection strings that are (allegedly) oracle-centric. In my experience, when I've used them (it's been a while) I think it was only `key=value` pairs, separated with semi-colons, and strings with spaces are encapsulated in braces instead of quotes.

Comment: @r2evans  Thank you for staying with this.  When I try: con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home1};Uid=username;Pwd=password;Host=website.com;Port=2879;service_name=pdblhs;")   (which is a little different than the strings you posted but similar in intent with the parens) I get a slightly different error of:  "Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed " This question on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69928017/trouble-accessing-oracle-database-using-r-odbc-package had same error and a comment that they needed to use the R 32 bit.  Maybe that?

Comment: I wouldn't think so: the output from `odbcListDrivers()` includes the specific driver name, which suggests that your OS has it in the 64-bit set of drivers, but you should verify that. I'm assuming you are on windows, so press the `<Win>` button and search for "odbc 64". Look there for the 64-bit Oracle driver. If you don't find it there but _do_ find it when searching within "odbc 32", then ... that may be it, and I'm a little confused about the state of your system.

Comment: @r2evans I was able to find it in the 64 one.  Hmm.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253974/discussion-between-r2evans-and-joe-crozier).

Comment: If you are using R, try the ROracle driver https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/roracle-downloads.html instead of ODBC.